# How to split XML file into many XML files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know how to write XSLT to split an XML file into multiple XML files according to these requirements:

- file1.xml - The lakes who type= Natyral
- file2.xml - The lakes who type=Artificial
- file3.xml - The lakes who type=Glacial

XML imput file is:

```
<Lakes>
  <Lake>
    <id>1</id>
    <Name>Caspian</Name>
    <Type>Natyral</Type>
  </Lake>
  <Lake>
    <id>2</id>
    <Name>Moreo</Name>
    <Type>Glacial</Type>
  </Lake>
  <Lake>
    <id>3</id>
    <Name>Sina</Name>
    <Type>Artificial</Type>
  </Lake>
</Lakes>
```

Comment: if efficiency is important, vtd-xml is another option, it is also simple to use, but require some coding.

Answer (score 22):

Use XSLT 2.0, like this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Lakes/Lake" group-by="Type">
            <xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
                <Lakes>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </Lakes>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: [`xsl:result-document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) instruction.

Answer (score 5):

With standard XSL it is not possible to have more than one output xml (i.e. resulting tree).
However, using Xalan [redirect](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html) extension, you can.

Have a look at the example on the page in the link.  I tested the following with Xalan Java 2.7.1

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Lakes/Lake[Type='Natyral']">
        <redirect:write file="/home/me/file1.xml">
            <NatyralLakes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </NatyralLakes>
        </redirect:write>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Lakes/Lake[Type='Artificial']">
        <redirect:write file="/home/me/file1.xml">
            <ArtificialLakes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </ArtificialLakes>
        </redirect:write>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Lakes/Lake[Type='Glacial']">
        <redirect:write file="/home/me/file3.xml">
            <GlacialLakes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </GlacialLakes>
        </redirect:write>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With XSLT 1.0 it's not possible... it's very possible in 2.0

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I was speaking about XSLT 1.0.  Since Xalan does/will not implement xslt 2.0, I stuck to 1.0 in my java code.  I could also have mentioned the exslt `document` extension that achieves a similar result for xslt 1.0

Comment: Please don't refer to XSLT 1.0 as "standard XSL". Lots of people are still using it, but it is no longer the standard.