# BASH SHELL SCRIPT to split a big xml file into multiple small files

Tags: xml, file, shell, split

I have a an XML file in below format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
    </child>
    <child>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
    </child>
 </parent>
```

I need a BASH SHELL script to split this main xml file into multiple small XML files which should have contents from the `<child>` to `</child>` tag. File names could be parent file name plus a running serial number such as _1 for ex:20110721_1.xml etc..
Please help me with the script.

Answer (score 9):

Not pure answer but you can tune this yourself:

```
csplit -ksf part. src.xml /\<child\>/ "{100}" 2>/dev/null
```

This command will split `src.xml` using regexp `/\<child\>/` as a delimiter and produce 1..100 `part.*` files.
You need to play with regexp though...

Comment: But it's good to use it in `bash` script to split a file. Ah, and thanks for -1 me...

Comment: Hey, this command is great if you happen to know your XML has regular structure. Is there any way to divide the original file into evenly sized (roughly) files?

Comment: This method is awesome - thank You for that NilColor

Comment: Most useful thanks. Using `-b%02d.xml` adds a nice .xml on the end.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to write a XSL file and use `xsltproc` with the stylesheet and the xml file to generate the single files.

See [How to split XML file into many XML files using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833361/how-to-split-xml-file-into-many-xml-files-using-xslt) for an example.