# Error when trying to split an XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been trying to split an large xml file by multiple files based on its nodes. I looked all over on internet and i found out that XSLT should do the job, however when i tried the example described in this post [How to split XML file into many XML files using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833361/how-to-split-xml-file-into-many-xml-files-using-xslt) and then accessed the xml file in the browser this message showed up: Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT transformation failed.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well browsers use XSLT 1.0 processors like libxslt, transformix or others and XSLT 1.0 does not support any way to create multiple result documents. You would need to move to an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML/Raptor to make use of XSLT 2.0 features like `xsl:result-document`.

Or you need to check whether an XSLT 1.0 processor you want to use supports an extension to create multiple result documents, libxslt might support that, but I am not sure what is supposed to happen when you try that in a browser, you would need to run it from the command line or your application code with file system access.

Comment: Thank you. Now it all makes sense. By chance, do you happen to know if there is a tutorial that could help me with using Saxon9 or all the others?

Comment: Saxon comes with a good documentation, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/about/index.html respectively http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.5HE and the download link. There are also XML IDEs like Stylus Studio or oXygen that make use of Saxon. Altova's XMLSpy is an IDE making use of Altova's AltovaXML/Raptor, I am sure they have lots of documentation too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally did it!Cheers!